# Clashing descenders on letters

Tags: line-spacing

I want almost no separation between lines.  How do I use an alternative form of a letter on a line that touches a descender on a letter from the line above?  If, for example, a g happens to be directly above a d, I want a form of d with a shortened upward piece.  This problem occurs in Hebrew text where there is a special form of a lamed with a bent-over top to be used when the the letter above is, say, a nun-sofit which descends well below the line.  This can happen hundreds of time in a text, so manual changes are not feasible.

Comment: tex can not detect this, so you would need to manually change the source to replace d by `\symbol{77}` assuming your font has the variant d at position 77

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't see how that would help at all.

Comment: @cfr - Sorry, I misunderstood the problem.